# Лайки для страниц сайта

Tags: поисковые-системы

Насколько мне известно, поисковые роботы обращают внимание на многие вещи для поднятия страниц в топы, и один из способов - лайки. Поиск в Интернете выдал лайк от googla, но я так понимаю, что другие поисковики эту информацию не воспримут.

Вопрос: есть универсальный лайк? 
Спасибо.

Это код от Googla для лайка в её систему:

```
<!-- Вставьте этот тег в заголовке страницы или непосредственно перед закрывающим тегом основной части. -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
  {lang: 'ru'}
</script>

<!-- Поместите этот тег туда, где должна отображаться виджет. -->
<div class="g-person" data-href="//plus.google.com/u/0/104910656186535314509" data-rel="author"></div>
```

Comment: если кратко, то [серебряной пули](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82) не существует.

Раскрутка в каждой поисковой системе - это свой квест. Но все таки есть один надеждный метод - качественный контент.

Comment: коды для лайка я и сам могу написать, спасибо. Что касается качества - согласен, качество и уникальность, вот основной алгоритм, но и ссылки и лаики, плюс коментарии играют немаловажную роль. Но вопрос - какие лайки используются? Если с обычной базой на txt, вряд ли. В лайках скорее всего будут учитываться не только клики, но и IP, и еще что то. Вот я и спрашиваю, какую базу надо создать для поисковиков и что в базу должно входить?

Comment: Так ваши лайки то на javascript. и поисковым ботам вообще все равно на них.

Answer (score 1):

Лайки никак не помогут вам в поднятии страниц, к сожалению. Дело в том, что гугл-бот не смотрит на JS при входе на сайт.
Для этого существует много других способов:

1. Качественный контент
2. Закупка ссылок
3. SEO-оптимизация страницы и т.д.
   Лайки - это всего лишь инструмент для изучения статистики в Google Analytics.

P.S. Для каждой поисковой системы сайт продвигается по-разному. Есть общие моменты, конечно, но основная часть делается под каждую поисковую систему отдельно.